# Can we say that a function is differentiable if it's partial derivates are continuous?/

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Suppose if $f$ is a function of $x,y$ and if $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ are continuous then can we say that $f$ is differentiable?

Note: We are not given anything about continuity of $f$.

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Comment: If you don't mind. Can you tell me how?? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Rought Solution: 
Observe
\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{f(a+h, b+k)-f(a, b)-f_x(a, b)h-f_y(a, b)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \right|\\
=&\left|\frac{f(a+h, b+k)-f(a,b+k)-f_x(a, b)h+f(a,b+k)-f(a, b)-f_y(a, b)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \right|\\
\leq&\  \left|\frac{f_x(\xi, b+k)h-f_x(a, b)h+f_y(a, \eta)k-f_y(a, b)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \right|\\
\leq&\ \sqrt{|f_x(\xi, b+k)-f_x(a, b)|^2+ |f_y(a,\eta)-f_y(a, b)|^2}
\end{align}
where the first inequality (actually an equality) comes from mean value theorem and second inequality comes from Cauchy-Schwarz.

Applying continuity of $f_x$ and $f_y$ now will finish the problem.